# creating an index did not change my query cost

Tags: database, postgresql, query-optimization

I was trying to decrease the cost of query execution by creating an index on the rating column. The table has 2680 tuples

```
 SELECT * from cup_matches WHERE rating*3 > 20
```

However when i used pgAdmin to view the query cost before and after indexing, it remained the same. I thought it would decrease as the processes of indexing should decrease the cost of data being taken from the hardisk, due to indexing (reducing I/O cost), to the memory. Can someone tell me why did it stay the same?

Comment: What is the execution plan? You can find this with the `EXPLAIN` or `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` command.

Comment: Why are you doing `rating*3 > 20` instead of `rating > 20/3`?

Comment: @jmelesky Seq Scan on cup_matches  (cost=0.00..61.20 rows=893 width=27) (actual time=0.026..1.114 rows=1215 loops=1) 
  Filter: ((rating * '3'::double precision) > '20'::double precision)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 1465
Planning time: 0.138 ms
Execution time: 1.226 ms

Comment: @BShaps would that cause the cost to remain the same?

Comment: @MarwaA. If you have an index on rating then it should.  Nick's explanation of why is pretty good.

Comment: Do **not** put code or additional information into comments. [edit] your question and make sure you preserve the indention when you add the execution plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cost did not diminish because you are doing a mutation operation within the where so it cannot use the index.  removing the "*3" operation should do the trick.

```
 SELECT * from cup_matches WHERE rating > 20
```

Should have the performance increase, because you are no longer mutating the rating value.  When values are mutated you need to do a complete table scan in order to do comparisons.

Comment: but why did the execution time decrease then?

Answer (score 0):

because the index is on `rating` and not on `rating*3`. To use your current index, try

```
SELECT * from cup_matches WHERE rating > 20/3
```

Comment: It should be mentioned 20/3 == 6 here.